# Disabling multi-master on live Cosmos DB database

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

The documentation indicates that multi-master support can be enabled on an existing account with zero downtime.  Is the reverse also possible (disable multi-master) without downtime?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is zero downtime when changing this back to single-master. Any clients that are connected to and writing to the region being returned as read-only will redirect to the primary region. Any reads will continue with no changes.